# Is there a way to change the location of the driver log output for a dataproc job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I'd like to have programmatic access to my driver logs after the job is finished and the cluster is deleted. I could store the job and cluster id somewhere to look it up later, but thought it would be easier to just tell dataproc to store the logs in a well-known location. Is there some way to override the location of the driver output for a spark job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not currently supported, but you can [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187133&template=0) on the public Dataproc [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

In the meantime though you could also consider specifying a custom `--bucket` at cluster creation time; the driver output and other cluster config files will go in whatever bucket you specify as the cluster config bucket instead of the default dataproc-created bucket in that case.